# Android Studio always load old revision of support library

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library

When I write code in Android Studio with some features from android support library it is ok, but when I try to build application, it cannot recognize some methods from support library. In "External library" I see that there is android-support-library revision 7, but in gradle file I  wrote

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

I can't figure out what's the problem? and how can i solve it, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the + sign:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

So you can choose any fixed version number.

However the newest version was on Friday 21.0.2. I didn't check it in the meantime.